# How to get color of texture1d at specified coordinate (OpenGL)?

Tags: opengl, textures, shader

*Example:* I have a one dimensional texture created by `glTexImage1D`, that stores simple gradient.

Before rendering some scales and translates are applied using transform matrix via `glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)`, after that I need to retrieve a pixel color of texture at some coordinate [0-1] and output RGB values to some text field.

Is this possible without using of shaders, just using direct OpenGL calls?

Comment: Are you using C _or_ C++? You have tagged both yet they are different languages.

Comment: Please note that *"just using direct OpenGL calls"* and usage of the OpenGL matrix stack is long deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

No need for shaders to do this. Read the texture from the GPU to the CPU using [glGetTexImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml). This will give you a texel array with the contents of your 1D texture. You then simply have to read the appropriate texel from this array based on your texel coordinates.